# ¿Cómo manejar el Tabs de JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando el tabs de `Jquery` en mi página,y me doy cuenta de algo muy incómodo de lo cual no se como arreglarlo.

Y es que, por ejemplo si estoy en la seccion 2 o 3 o 4 de ese tabs y recargo la pagina este me vuelve a la seccion 1.

Quiero que aunque recargue la pagina ese tab en el que estaba se quede ahi.
No tengo codigo porque lo enlazo directamente al CDN.

Hay alguna forma de arreglar eso?

Comment: Es buena práctica aquí en Stack Overflow compartir lo que has hecho para tratar de resolver. ¿Puedes compartir código?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **sessionStorage** para guardar el valor de la última tab que has pulsado y recuperarlo al recargar la página.

Necesitarás acceder al valor de posición de cada tab, yo he usado un data attribute para esto:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li data-index="0"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li data-index="1"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li data-index="2"><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Almacenamos el valor de data-index en nuestra key "tabActiva":

```
  $("#tabs").on('click', '.ui-tabs-tab', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var tabindex = $(this).data('index');
      sessionStorage.setItem('tabActiva', tabindex);
    });
```

Y por último recuperamos el valor almacenado en **sessionStorage** al recargar la página:

```
var ultimaTabActiva = function(){
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('tabActiva');
    return (data !== null)? data : 0;
}
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
   active: ultimaTabActiva()
});
```

Aquí tienes un ejempo funcionando:

http://codepen.io/jreyesgs/pen/QGvVNO